# How to add linux dependencies to an electron app?

Tags: linux, electron, electron-builder, electron-packager, electron-forge

How would one add any dependency to an electron app for .deb and .rpm packages?
So that the user on installing is not just installing the electron app but also a dependency if it is not already installed like any package you can install via `apt-get install` or `rpm install`

Comment: check https://github.com/ollm/OpenComic/blob/9a717c4fd1c4570b9f4ed800913ad31ca4251032/package.json#L152 or electron-installer-debian

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. I will check this!

Comment: The github link pointed above works extremely well, I was looking on how to add JRE to my electron application for about 1 week, following his link helped me make it work for Ubuntu application.